Error Parsing Attribute in Rust Procedural Macro
I'm working through the dtolnay proc-macro-workshop to learn about Rust procedural macros. As part of an exercise, I'm trying to create a derive macro that generates a builder struct for each struct annotated with the #[derive(Builder)] macro.
Here is the struct I'm working with in main.rs:
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct Command {
    executable: String,
    #[builder(each = "arg")]
    args: Vec<String>,
    #[builder(each = "env")]
    env: Vec<String>,
    current_dir: Option<String>,
}

I'm encountering an issue while parsing the #[builder(each = "arg")] attribute in my procedural macro. The goal is to ensure the attribute follows a specific structure and to extract the expression from it. However, I'm getting an Err object when parsing the attribute even though it appears to be correctly set.
Here is the function I'm using to validate and parse the attribute:
fn is_valid_vec_attribute(
    attrs: &Vec<syn::Attribute>,
) -> Result<syn::Ident, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    if attrs.len() != 1 {
        panic!("Only 1 attribute is authorized");
    }
    
    let attr = &attrs[0];

    if let syn::Meta::List(ref meta_list) = attr.meta {
        if !meta_list.path.is_ident("builder") {
            panic!("Attribute path must be `builder`");
        }

        let data: Result<syn::Expr, syn::Error> = attr.parse_args();
        println!("{:#?}", data);

        // Additional processing of `data` here...

    } else {
        panic!("Only List attributes are allowed like such: `path(..)`");
    }

    // Return a valid identifier for now
    Ok(syn::Ident::new("dummy", proc_macro2::Span::call_site()))
}

When running this code, the data variable results in an Err object. Here's the debug output I'm seeing:
Err(
    Error(
        "unexpected token",
    ),
)

What I've Tried:

Ensured that the attribute path is correctly identified as builder.
Checked the structure of the Meta::List to confirm it is correct.

Here is a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate the issue:
main.rs
#[derive(Builder)]
pub struct Command {
    executable: String,
    #[builder(each = "arg")]
    args: Vec<String>,
    #[builder(each = "env")]
    env: Vec<String>,
    current_dir: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {}

lib.rs
fn is_valid_vec_attribute(
    attrs: &Vec<syn::Attribute>,
) -> Result<syn::Ident, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    if let 1 = attrs.len() {
        let attr = &attrs[0];

        if let syn::Meta::List(ref meta_list) = attr.meta {
            if !meta_list.path.is_ident("builder") {
                panic!("Attribute path must be `builder`");
            }

            let data: Result<syn::Expr, syn::Error> = attr.parse_args();
            println!("{:#?}", data);
        } else {
            panic!("Only List attribute are allowed like such: `path(..)`")
        };
    };
    panic!("Only 1 attributes is authorized");
}


#[proc_macro_derive(Builder, attributes(builder))]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let DeriveInput { ident, data, .. } = syn::parse(input).unwrap();
    let builder_name_ident = Ident::new(&format!("{}Builder", ident), Span::call_site());

    match data {
        syn::Data::Struct(data) => {
            let fields = data.fields.iter().map(|f| {
                let name = &f.ident;
                let mut ty = &f.ty;
                let x = is_valid_vec_attribute(&f.attrs);
                if let (_, BaseType::Option, Some(_ty)) = extract_generic_type(&f.attrs, ty) {
                    ty = _ty;
                }

                quote! {
                    #name: Option<#ty>
                }
            });

            let expanded = quote! {
                pub struct #builder_name_ident {
                    #(#fields,)*
                }
            };

            expanded.into()
        }
        _ => panic!("Only struct are allowed"),
    }
}

PS: I found that the error is coming from '=' inside;
#[builder(each = "arg")]

indeed when I replace the '=' by let's say '<' or any other token like so:
#[builder(each < "arg")]

it works perfectly why ?

I was not able to reproduce, but your "minimal reproducible example" was not as reproducible as it first seemed. Your example struct always triggers a panic because you're expecting one attribute per field, but some don't have one. Fixing that, your is_valid_vec_attribute above works fine, while the one below has an unconditional panic at the end. Weird. And lastly syn::Expr doesn't implement Debug so println!("{:#?}", data) doesn't work. If this is working for you, what version are you using? You also didn't provide extract_generic_type but that doesn't seem important at the moment.

Oops, my bad about the Debug thing, I didn't realize it was gated behind an "extra-traits" feature, but the rest still stands. The first code seems to work just fine.
